# Does the order of data and non-data functions [theme(), scale_*_*(), guides(), coord_*(), etc] in ggplot2 matter?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've always wondered if there are some subtle changes that I haven't noticed, or potential errors and unnecessary workarounds, based on how ggplot code is structured. When searching for an answer, all I ever find are examples of how the order of geoms affect the resulting plot, but I'm curious about the order of all the other pieces, too.

I haven't found any "best practices" or "standard usage"; for the most part it seems like everyone has their own ways of writing their code. Some build plots piece-by-piece, like so:

```
library(tidyverse)

base <- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour = drv)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = TRUE) +
  theme(legend.direction = "horizontal",
               legend.key = element_blank(),
               legend.position = c(0.6,0.1),
               legend.title = element_blank(),
               panel.background = element_blank())

base <- base + scale_colour_manual(labels = c("Front", "Rear", "4WD"),
                                   values = c("black", "orange", "blue")) +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = c(22),
                                                   fill = c("black", "orange", "blue"),
                                                   size = 10))) +
  coord_flip()

(base <- base + facet_wrap(. ~ class))
```

I prefer doing it all at once, and in general, I usually structure my code something like this:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour = drv)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = TRUE) + 
  theme(legend.direction = "horizontal",
        legend.key = element_blank(),
        legend.position = c(0.6,0.1),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank()) +
  scale_colour_manual(labels = c("Front", "Rear", "4WD"),
                      values = c("black", "orange", "blue")) +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = c(22),
                                                   fill = c("black", "orange", "blue"),
                                                   size = 10))) +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_wrap(. ~ class)
```

From what I can tell, it makes no difference (visually, in the resulting plot) if I structure it like this (keeping geom_point and geom_smooth in the same relative order, though):

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) + 
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = c(22),
                                                   fill = c("black", "orange", "blue"),
                                                   size = 10))) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = drv)) +
  facet_wrap(. ~ class) +
  theme(legend.direction = "horizontal",
        legend.key = element_blank(),
        legend.position = c(0.6,0.1),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank()) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = TRUE) + 
  coord_flip() + 
  scale_colour_manual(labels = c("Front", "Rear", "4WD"),
                      values = c("black", "orange", "blue"))
```

This is just a simple example, and I often have several other geoms and make manual tweaks to all aspects of the plot. Are there cases when problems may arise based on the ordering of functions with more complex code?

Comment: Order generally doesn't matter. For parts like theme, the last value set takes precedent. But if you aren't redundantly trying to re-set a property you already set, it doesn't matter.

Comment: When there are repeated elements, the last one will be used. So if you accidentally have 2 `scale_y_*`, the last one will take effect (with a warning).

Comment: I'm aware that the last element/value/redundant piece of code will be the one that takes effect. It's the _generally_ doesn't matter that makes me worried about when it might _specifically_ matter.